# Ajax not working with owl-carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I m having a probleme with implementing ajax in my page which countain owl-carousel her is the code :

Controller:

```
 public int Getmembers()
    {

        return db.Teams.Count();

        }
    }
```

The View :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
                        var json = null;
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("Getmembers", "Home")',
                            type: "GET",
                            dataType: "int",
                            success: function (data) {
                                json = data;

                            },
                            error: function () {
                                alert("Erreur de récupération des membres ou il n'existe aucun memnbre");
                            }

                        })
                        alert(json);
                        var owl = $("#owl-demo");

                        owl.owlCarousel({
                            items: json, //10 items above 1000px browser width
                            itemsDesktop: [1000, 5], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
                            itemsDesktopSmall: [900, 3], // betweem 900px and 601px
                            itemsTablet: [600, 2], //2 items between 600 and 0
                            itemsMobile: false, // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option
                            pagination: false

                        });


                    });
</script>
```

I tried debugging and i discovered that in the   $.ajax the value of json is passed (an int 13) but when i use alert i get null , i searched in the documentation got this http://www.jq22.com/demo/OwlCarousel2/demos/ajax.html  but still having no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax call is async which means it will execute the success method after your owl carousel initialization.

Put the init method of your carousel into the success method:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var json = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Getmembers", "Home")',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "int",
        success: function (data) {
            var owl = $("#owl-demo");

            owl.owlCarousel({
                items: data, //10 items above 1000px browser width
                itemsDesktop: [1000, 5], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
                itemsDesktopSmall: [900, 3], // betweem 900px and 601px
                itemsTablet: [600, 2], //2 items between 600 and 0
                itemsMobile: false, // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option
                pagination: false

            });

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Erreur de récupération des membres ou il n'existe aucun memnbre");
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, forgot to initialize the owl carousell worked fine !